# Possibility of Using Mono on Android for Android 1.5

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I know that Mono on Android only officially supports Android 1.6 and above, but I was wondering if anyone had any experience or tips for trying to get it to work on Android 1.5?

I've tried manually changing the manifest sdk version (even inside the sdk itself), but when I try to install the app, all I get is an unsupported SDK version.

Note that I understand that officially Mono on Android does not support 1.6, but I'm looking for an [unsupported/experimental/hack] way to do it.  I'd even settle for a generic apk sdk version change, but my google-fu could not find such a program (and who knows if it would even work with Mono).

Comment: For shipping in a product or your own personal edification?

Comment: Personal edification - the Android 1.5 platform is a rooted e-ink nook and I'd like to program it using Mono on Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question in case anyone else tries it.

Mono on Android looks for a android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo, which was added in 1.6, so it seems that it's not possible to run Mono on Android on Android lower than 1.6.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just set the Minimum Android to Target to 1.6, add an AndroidManifest.xml using the project properties, but then edit it manually in the Properties folder and change the minSdkVersion from 4 to 3.  The Intellisense will still target 1.6, so you'll need to ensure you don't use any newer API.

However, this is untested and unsupported.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  It builds and packages cleanly at least, but on the device is fails with a "Could not find method android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo, referenced from method.mono.MonoRuntimeProvider.attachInfo".  A google search reveals this is because Mono on Android does not support 1.5.